# Operator K-theory and the unitary group

Tags: c-star-algebras, k-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a C*-algebra whose unitary group is contractible (e.g. $B(H)$ or more generally the stable multiplier algebra of any C*-algebra).  It is clear from the definition that $K_1(A) = 0$, but I think it is also true that $K_0(A)$ is necessarily $0$.  Is this correct?  Is there an elementary proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea: To show that $K_1(A)=0$ you actually only use that $U(A)$ is *path connected*. Now it suffices to show that $U(\Sigma A)$ (unitary group of suspension) is path connected if $U(A)$ is contractible.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it does the job.  I was secretly hoping for something that doesn't involve Bott periodicity, but that might just be too much to hope for.